# plot more than one graph in zedgraph

Tags: zedgraph

I am trying to draw 5 graph on one zedgraph mens one x-asix and 5 y-axis. It works but it not look better. please help me.
here is my code what m trying

```
GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl2.GraphPane;

myPane.Title.Text = "Longituidnal Graph";
myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "station Number";
myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "BuoyanceUDL";

double[] XstnNo = { 0, 1.3, 2.6, 3.9, 5.2, 6.5, 7.8, 9.1, 10.4, 11.7, 13, 14.3, 15.6, 16.9, 18.2, 19.5, 20.8, 22.1, 23.4, 24.7, 26, 27.3, 28.6, 29.9, 31.2, 32.5, 33.8, 35.1, 36.4, 37.7, 39, 40.3, 41.6, 42.9, 44.2, 45.5, 46.8, 48.1, 49.4, 50.7, 52, 53.3, 54.6, 55.9, 57.2, 58.5, 59.8, 61.1, 62.4 };

double[] YBuoyanceUDL= { 0,0.194,0.44,0.497,1.232,3.592,7.345,11.188,14.403,16.708,18.165,18.897,19.142,19.158,18.935,18.983,18.538,18.345,18.153,17.951,17.748,17.568,17.365,17.163,16.982,16.779,16.577,16.386,16.195,15.994,15.804,15.603,15.414,15.225,15.019,14.782,14.548,14.248,13.867,13.408,12.86,12.262,11.654,11.052,10.357,9.179,6.692,1.807,0 };
double[] YNetUDL= { 6.954, 13.714, 13.468, 15.135, 14.4, 9.226, 5.473, 1.179, -2.036, -2.307, -3.764, 0.188, -0.057, -2.41, -2.187, -4.264, -3.819, -4.918, -4.726, -6.501, -6.298, -6.639, -6.436, -6.531, -6.35, -1.794, -1.592, -6.968, -6.777, -9.852, -9.662, -9.351, -9.162, -9.131, -8.925, -8.773, -8.539, 1.243, 1.624, 3.187, 3.735, -5.122, -4.514, -3, -2.305, 14.944, 17.431, 24.671, 26.478 };
double[] YSF = { 0,22.222,39.73,59.406,78.126,90.12,97.235,98.768,96.121,93.122,88.229,88.473,88.399,85.266,82.423,76.88,71.915,65.522,59.378,50.927,42.74,34.109,25.742,17.252,8.997,6.665,4.595,-4.463,-13.273,-26.081,-38.642,-50.798,-62.709,-74.579,-86.182,-97.587,-108.688,-107.072,-104.961,-100.818,-95.963,-102.622,-108.49,-112.39,-115.387,-95.96,-73.3,-41.228,-6.807};
double[] YInv_Len = { 62.4,61.1,59.8,58.5,57.2,55.9,54.6,53.3,52,50.7,49.4,48.1,46.8,45.5,44.2,42.9,41.6,40.3,39,37.7,36.4,35.1,33.8,32.5,31.2,29.9,28.6,27.3,26,24.7,23.4,22.1,20.8,19.5,18.2,16.9,15.6,14.3,13,11.7,10.4,9.1,7.8,6.5,5.2,3.9,2.6,1.3,0};
double[] YFinalBM = { 0, 65.215, 162.931, 283.197, 407.846, 518.041, 621.064, 714.915, 836.015, 963.904, 1097.644, 1235.457, 1375.695, 1509.816, 1629.31, 1733.849, 1823.132, 1896.957, 1955.14, 1997.258, 2022.887, 2034.449, 2034.398, 2027.087, 2016.916, 1999.886, 1971.973, 1933.102, 1883.183, 1822.331, 1750.665, 1669.503, 1580.194, 1483.496, 1379.97, 270.983, 1158.113, 1043.147, 928.289, 810.43, 687.434, 560.766, 433.358, 311.55, 202.144, 112.676, 48.162, 7.826, 0 };

LineItem BuoyanceUDLCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Smooth ", XstnNo, YBuoyanceUDL, Color.Purple, SymbolType.Diamond);
BuoyanceUDLCurve.Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.Red);
BuoyanceUDLCurve.Symbol.Size = 3;

LineItem NetUDLCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Smooth ", XstnNo,YNetUDL, Color.Green, SymbolType.Circle);
NetUDLCurve.Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.Red );
NetUDLCurve.Symbol.Size = 3;

LineItem SFCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Smooth ", XstnNo, YSF, Color.Magenta, SymbolType.Plus);
SFCurve.Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.Gray);
SFCurve.Symbol.Size = 3;

LineItem Inv_LenCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Smooth ", XstnNo, YInv_Len, Color.Olive , SymbolType.Triangle);
Inv_LenCurve.Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.Orchid );
Inv_LenCurve.Symbol.Size = 3;

LineItem FinalBMCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Smooth", XstnNo, YFinalBM, Color.Red, SymbolType.XCross);
FinalBMCurve.Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.Purple);
FinalBMCurve.Symbol.Size = 3;

zedGraphControl2.AxisChange();
```

Comment: Still wanting to do it ?

Comment: Nop...got best solution ..b4 ur question